# Snowflake JDBC driver metadata extraction custom attributes

Tags: jdbc, metadata, driver, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While configuring the JDBC driver to extract metadata from Snowflake like tables, columns, views - what attributes I should make use of to extract table descriptions, column descriptions, tags associated to tables etc.

Also, is there a place wherein I can see the exhaustive list of metadata attributes.

When I configured the snowflake JDBC driver in Collibra data catalog, it fetches only table names but not descriptions, column names but not descriptions.

Comment: Hi - have you looked at the documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-api.html ? Which jdbc objects/methods are you calling to try to get the information you require?

Answer (score 0):

To get an exhaustive list, use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html#information-schema). Each database has an `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema within it with a bunch of useful information. You can also use the [SNOWFLAKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#what-is-the-snowflake-database) database which holds similar information across the account.

These two options will probably give you more information than you can get from the JDBC api.